# OPENJSON - Unable to query nested elements

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I'm having difficulty querying the nested elements of a JSON document using the T-SQL `OPENJSON` function in SQL Server 2016. I read through the MSDN docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) , [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  & [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-openjson-with-an-explicit-schema-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) yet havent found the correct syntax for the WITH block. My columns keep returning only a single null row.

Can anyone please assist in modifying the T-SQL to achieve query output like this (below)?

[image]

Here is the json structure & null output:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  N'{"meta":{"total_record_count":4870,"total_pages":98,"current_page":97,"per_page":50},"companies":[{"id":"13463591","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13463591","company_name":"Modula4","domain":"modula4.com"},{"id":"13531979","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13531979","company_name":"Rae Development Corp","domain":"raedevelopment.com"},{"id":"13537660","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537660","company_name":"jBASE","domain":"jbase.com"},{"id":"13537769","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537769","company_name":"D2Effects LLC","domain":"bitefx.com"},{"id":"13537784","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537784","company_name":"eSyncTraining","domain":"esynctraining.com"},{"id":"13541751","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13541751","company_name":"Business Computing","domain":"bcinc.net"},{"id":"13553270","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13553270","company_name":"KNIGHTLING INC.","domain":"knightling.com"},{"id":"13560476","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13560476","company_name":"Netcentric systems","domain":"netcentricsystems.com"},{"id":"13560643","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13560643","company_name":"Fortium Solutions, LLC","domain":"fortiumsolutions.com"},{"id":"13561893","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13561893","company_name":"PMAC SERVICES INC","domain":"pmacservices.com"},{"id":"13587256","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13587256","company_name":"Bayonet Inc.","domain":"mybayonet.com"},{"id":"13590982","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13590982","company_name":"IQA","domain":"instrumentalqa.com"},{"id":"13593143","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13593143","company_name":"Atech Consultants","domain":"atechconsultants.com"},{"id":"13601156","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13601156","company_name":"Csoft Corp","domain":"csoftcorp.net"},{"id":"13602832","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13602832","company_name":"Gareth, Inc.","domain":"garethinc.com"},{"id":"13604890","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13604890","company_name":"Xpaseo","domain":"xpaseo.com"},{"id":"13610146","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13610146","company_name":"Imagine IT","domain":"imagineit.com"},{"id":"13610923","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13610923","company_name":"HTS Solutions Pvt Ltd","domain":"htssolutions.org"},{"id":"13619836","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13619836","company_name":"Tgm Software","domain":"tgmsoftware.com"},{"id":"13622956","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13622956","company_name":"Inaspan LLC","domain":"inaspan.com"},{"id":"13627130","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13627130","company_name":"Forerunner Systems Inc","domain":"forerunnersystems.com"},{"id":"13628312","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13628312","company_name":"Advanced Integrated Solutions, Inc.","domain":"aisconsulting.net"},{"id":"13629029","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13629029","company_name":"Pounce Consulting","domain":"pouncecorp.com"},{"id":"13629537","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13629537","company_name":"CloudServe Corporation","domain":"cloudservecorp.com"},{"id":"13635102","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13635102","company_name":"Leivio Technologies","domain":"leivio.com"},{"id":"13636749","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13636749","company_name":"Alpen Technology Group","domain":"alpentg.com"},{"id":"13636754","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13636754","company_name":"National Schedule Masters","domain":"tractime.com"},{"id":"13645065","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13645065","company_name":"RISA Technologies","domain":"risa.com"},{"id":"13646467","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13646467","company_name":"Enterprise Answers, LLC","domain":"enterpriseanswers.com"},{"id":"13647801","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13647801","company_name":"Office Automation Centers Inc","domain":"officeautomationcenter.com"},{"id":"13650810","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13650810","company_name":"Mozgomedia","domain":"mozgomedia.com"},{"id":"13652763","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13652763","company_name":"2000 Networking","domain":"network2000-hi.com"},{"id":"13654103","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13654103","company_name":"Vega Imaging","domain":"vega-imaging.com"},{"id":"13654874","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13654874","company_name":"Astha Inc.","domain":"asthainc.com"},{"id":"13656103","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13656103","company_name":"Management Applied Programming","domain":"mapinc.com"},{"id":"13657848","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13657848","company_name":"4Hilton Inc.","domain":"4hilton.com"},{"id":"13658020","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13658020","company_name":"FCC Group","domain":"fccgroup.com"},{"id":"13658316","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13658316","company_name":"Wavelength Datacom, Inc.","domain":"wavdata.com"},{"id":"13661074","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13661074","company_name":"Xintex Corporation","domain":"xintex.com"},{"id":"13663085","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13663085","company_name":"DCL Media Services","domain":"onlinecopycorp.com"},{"id":"13667881","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13667881","company_name":"LMSPros","domain":"lmspros.com"},{"id":"13669354","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13669354","company_name":"Sujansky \u0026 Associates, LLC","domain":"sujansky.com"},{"id":"13669681","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13669681","company_name":"Felosoft LLC","domain":"felosoft.com"},{"id":"13669759","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13669759","company_name":"Collaborative Technologies Inc","domain":"collaborationtech.net"},{"id":"13670474","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13670474","company_name":"Freight Stream Inc","domain":"freightstream.com"},{"id":"13675681","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13675681","company_name":"eDimension Consulting","domain":"edimensionconsulting.com"},{"id":"13676806","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13676806","company_name":"LTT Net Solutions","domain":"lttnetsolutions.com"},{"id":"13678223","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13678223","company_name":"OCRTI Consulting Corp","domain":"ocrti.com"},{"id":"13679946","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13679946","company_name":"Mac Networks","domain":"macnetworks.com"},{"id":"13681009","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13681009","company_name":"NetMost Web Technologies","domain":"netmostwebdesign.com"}],"total_companies":4870,"page":97,"per_page":50}'

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (   
       id     int '$.companies.id' ,  
       [url]  nvarchar(max) '$.companies.url',  
       company_name nvarchar(max) '$.companies.company_name',  
       domain nvarchar(max)'$.companies.domain'  
     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all your `JSON` data as result set, you need additional `APPLY` operator with second `OPENJSON()` call (for nested `JSON` array), using explicit schema definition:

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   j.total_companies, j.page, j.per_page,
   a.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (   
   total_companies int '$.total_companies',
   page int '$.page',
   per_page int '$.per_page',
   companies nvarchar(max) '$.companies' AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.companies) 
WITH (
   id nvarchar(10) '$.id',
   url nvarchar(max) '$.url',
   company_name nvarchar(100) '$.company_name',
   domain nvarchar(max) '$.domain'
) a
```

Output (only first 10 records from 50):

```
total_companies page    per_page    id          url                                             company_name            domain
4870            97      50          13463591    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13463591   Modula4                 modula4.com
4870            97      50          13531979    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13531979   Rae Development Corp    raedevelopment.com
4870            97      50          13537660    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537660   jBASE                   jbase.com
4870            97      50          13537769    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537769   D2Effects LLC           bitefx.com
4870            97      50          13537784    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537784   eSyncTraining           esynctraining.com
4870            97      50          13541751    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13541751   Business Computing      bcinc.net
4870            97      50          13553270    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13553270   KNIGHTLING INC.         knightling.com
4870            97      50          13560476    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13560476   Netcentric systems      netcentricsystems.com
4870            97      50          13560643    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13560643   Fortium Solutions, LLC  fortiumsolutions.com
4870            97      50          13561893    https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13561893   PMAC SERVICES INC       pmacservices.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Companies is array in your case. Array element number has to be chosen to see the data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (   
       id     INT '$.companies[0].id' ,  
       [url]  NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.companies[0].url',  
       company_name NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.companies[0].company_name',  
       domain NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.companies[0].domain'  
     )
;
```

Comment: this query only returns the first company element. I'm looking to return ALL companies in the company array.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple...

Your JSON consists of two objects, first is `meta` and seems to be `1:1` related content. This is best queried using direct calls to `JSON_VALUE()`.

The second, `companies` is a nested JSON-array. Try this (shortened for brevity)

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  N'{"meta":{"total_record_count":4870,"total_pages":98,"current_page":97,"per_page":50},"companies":[{"id":"13463591","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13463591","company_name":"Modula4","domain":"modula4.com"},{"id":"13531979","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13531979","company_name":"Rae Development Corp","domain":"raedevelopment.com"},{"id":"13537660","url":"https://api.mattermark.com/companies/13537660","company_name":"jBASE","domain":"jbase.com"}]}'
```

-this brings back the `meta` values

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.meta.total_record_count') AS total_record_count
        ,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.meta.total_pages') AS total_pages
        ,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.meta.current_page') AS current_page
        ,JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.meta.per_page') AS per_page
```

--and this brings back the `companies` array:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.companies')
WITH (   
       id     int ,  
       [url]  nvarchar(max),  
       company_name nvarchar(max),  
       domain nvarchar(max)  
     ) A;
```

Hint: If needed you might combine them with a `CROSS JOIN`...